# how and where can I set MONO_IOMAP=all in Nginx

Tags: nginx, mono

I am using Mono(asp.net mvc) in Ubuntu, to solve case sensitive problems I have to set IOMAP all.

Unfortunately, I only found Apache sample(http://www.mono-project.com/IOMap), anyone can tell me how to accomplish this in Nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at the following links:

https://serverfault.com/a/452835/20853

http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?11,121225,164503

When you start `fastcgi-mono-server` you can:

```
MONO_IOMAP=all  fastcgi-mono-server4 /address=127.0.0.1 /applications=/:/srv/www/ /socket=tcp:9000 &
```

Or you can:

```
export MONO_IOMAP=all  
fastcgi-mono-server4 /address=127.0.0.1 /applications=/:/srv/www/ /socket=tcp:9000 &
```